# Relations on groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Define a relation on elements of $G$ by saying that $a \sim b$ if $b^{-1} a \in H$. This relation is :

- a) reflexive and symmetric, but transitive only if G is abelian.
- b) reflexive and transitive, but symmetric only if G is abelian.
- c) reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

My instinct would be to answer b) because abelian implies commutativity. However, I may be wrong but I don’t think it’s a).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a \sim b$ iff $aH=bH$ (*). This should make it easy to answer the question.

In general, every relation on a set $X$ defined by the equality of values of a function on $X$ must be an equivalence relation because equality is an equivalence relation.

Here, $X=G$ and the function is $a \mapsto aH$.

(*) Indeed:

$a \sim b \implies aH = eaH = (bb^{-1})aH = b(b^{-1}a)H = b(b^{-1}aH)=bH$, because $b^{-1}a\in H$.

$aH=bH \implies a=ae=bh \implies b^{-1}a=h\in H$.

Comment: So we don't require G to be abelian, do we ?

Comment: No, it does not depend on $G$ being abelian.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$a^{-1}a = 1 \in H$, so $\sim$ is reflexive

$a \sim b
 \rightarrow b^{-1}a \in H
 \rightarrow \left(b^{-1} a\right)^{-1} = a^{-1} b \in H
 \rightarrow b \sim a$ so it is symmetric

can you check transitivity?

Comment: So it is reflexive and symmetric even if G is not abelian ? So it's either answer a) or c). I am not sure how to check transitivity, I guess it's if a ~ b → b$^−$ &sup1; a ∈ H and then same thing for b ~ c and we want to see if a ~ c, right ?

Comment: It looks transitive to me but I am not sure of the condition of the abelian group, that's the only thing. (c^-1.b)(b^-1.a) gives c^-1.a and I think that the product of 2 elements in a group is in the group (def of a group). So I would say c) is correct but maybe I missed something.

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg transitivity means $a\sim b$ and $b \sim c$ imply $a\sim c$. So assume $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$. So $b^{-1} a \in H$ and $c^{-1}b \ in H$. What can you say about $c^{-1}a$ -- is it in $H$ or not?